# How to prevent extraction of android apk source code from attackers?

Tags: android, security

I have an existing released Android app in google play. But some hacker extract  source code from apk and use our services.I have already implement proguard + Base64  but even through hacker extract source code from apk. How can i prevent my apk from extraction?

Comment: I think it is enought ro run ProGuard and attacker doesnt have much chance to read it...doesnt matter if he can extract,but he cannot (he has very.little chance) to understand it. You cannot prevent extraction,because Android arhitecture relies in just in time compiling so the source code must be avaiable to system and therefore to potential attacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cant prevent extraction.
- Can do proguard but a good attacker it wont stop, because he can
  decompile your and reverse engineer it. Then he can listen to your
  LogCat, Binder, sniff communication...
- On the other hand u can do a lot of stuff to make your code better.
  Use SSL learn how to use proguard better so it ill be harder for
  them, dont write anything to log, encrypt data.